# Query result as an HTML table

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am not a expert on php html. I built a website 2 months ago, and realized I using lot of php query result on web. Is there any approach without while my query result on multiple times

```
<table>
<tbody>
<?php 
$proc = "{call p_rpt_str310Web (?,?,?)}";
$params = array($PlanPkID,$bycatID,$ByDateVal);  
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $proc, $params);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
{   
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $count; ?></td>
<td class="alignLefter"><?php echo $row['CusName']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['CusCount']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['WorkTime']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have code like this in my html multiple times is there any way to do something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to improve this code. but the two most basic ones would be

1. To create a simple helper function in order to avoid the repetitive code when running a query.
2. To separate the database interaction from the presentation logic, making the application more flexible, maintainable and clean-looking.

And one way of improvement I would advise against of: a function that would automate the HTML table creation. Although for the most primitive cases it would do, in reality there are no primitive cases, and you'll end up with a monster that takes more code to configure than to write just plain HTML, and it would completely unreadable compared with a straightforward HTML template.

**A function.**

```
function sqlsrv($conn, $sql, $params)
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    $return = [];
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
        $return = $row;
    }
}
```

this function accepts a connection, an arbitrary query and an array of parameters, and returns a simple array with returned rows.

You can put this function's definition into the same file where your connection is made.

**Code separation**

This one is simple. Always split your scripts into two parts: data manipulation (AKA business logic) and a template (aka presentation logic). So you can refactor your code like this

```
$data = sqlsrv($conn, "{call p_rpt_str310Web (?,?,?)}",[$PlanPkID,$bycatID,$ByDateVal]);
?>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <? php foreqach ($data as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $count ?></td>
      <td class="alignLefter"><?= $row['CusName'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row['CusCount'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row['WorkTime'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```